# authenticate member through database with hashed/salted password

Tags: java, mysql, ipb

i am using ipb forum software. I have member table with name entity and members_pass_hash and members_pass_salt. I have problem writing query statement to authorize member

```
    String Sql="Select * from members where name=? and members_pass_hash=?";
```

I know this is wrong, because password is not stored as plain text but i have no idea what to do.

I want to do this in java and i can't find any guides on this. Been searching for all day, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You got a spare " at the end of the SQL command. The ; is also not needed except for the mySQL command line client (may cause an error depending on your client library).

A salted password hash is usually verified by getting the salt string (sometimes it's stored as a prefix to the hashed password), calculating the salt and comparing the result.

In Pseudo-Code:

```
($id, $salt, $stored_hashed_password) = SELECT id, salt, hashed_password FROM members WHERE name=?
$entered_hash_password = hash_password($salt, $entered_cleartext_password)
if ($entered_hash_password == $stored_hash_password) {
   say "Yeah, you got it!";
} else {
   say "Go away!";
}
```

The comparison must obviously be a string comparison.

Update:
Very simple example about hashed passwords:

Cleartext password: 10
Salt "string": 5
Hash function: $cleartext * $salt
Hashed password: 50

No one could extract the original password out of the hashed password. The password may be 25, 1, 50, 10, 5.

Real hash functions are much more complicated and unreversable.

The hash_password() function used in the pseudo-code sample **MUST** be the one used when initially hashing the passwords for storing them into the database. Check the source code functions used for "change your password"

Comment: i fixed query, i have it in .java file :) I don't understand  how to setup hash_password now? do i need to convert string they enter to hash password?

Comment: I added some more text to the answer. I think IPB is written in PHP, so you should go for this. Otherwise you need to rebuild the same password hash routine in Java. Or start with a real programming language ignoring both Java (just a proof-of-concept for OOP) and PHP (Perl hypertext preprocessor as to their own homepage) ;)

Comment: thanks for adding more information, yeah IPB is written in PHP, but my java application is desktop application which needs access to forum database. I have seen many ipb forums having java desktop app with credentials from ipb members account. Can i do this anyway easier in long term? maybe webservice? do you suggest me anything? I am using jdbc mysql driver for now

Comment: You could probably use a HTTP call to verify the login data, but you'd need to write a PHP script for that. The bad way would be calling the login form target of the board and parsing the response page for the success or error message. A SOAP-based webservice is way too much complicated, but also possible.